# clang-format: separate system includes from standard library includes and external includes

Tags: c++, clang-format

To be more clear,

- Standard library headers include:

  - C standard library headers with their C (like `stdio.h`) or C++ (`cstdio`) name
  - C++ STL headers (`vector`, `limits`, `type_traits`, etc.)
- System headers include:

  - POSIX headers and their Windows UCRT equivalents (`sys/types.h`, `fcntl.h`, etc.)
  - Windows headers (`windows.h`, `psapi.h`, etc.)
- External headers are everything not listed here.

The only method I see of doing this is to write really long regexes, which I believe will definitely hurt performance (Windows has over 1000 different headers). Is there a nicer way of doing this?

Comment: Note that changing the ordering of the `#include` directives could change the meaning of the program in some cases (simply inserting blank lines between them would be safe, though)